# ubuntu 16.04 not showing font fully

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, fonts

I am trying to write text on Digital-7 font using Ubuntu 16.04.
But Libre-writer cannot display the font fully. In windows however Digital-7 font had shown fully. Attached Libre-writer's screenshot showing Digital-7 font. Please tell me any suggestions to display the font fully.

[image: Digital-7 writing example]

Comment: What happens if you increase the line spacing?

Comment: May I ask where did you get the digital 7 files?

Comment: @Anwar the font is in this link http://www.fonts2u.com/digital-7-italic.font . I found the solution. It is on Answers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333582/why-text-is-cutting-from-bottom-in-uitextfield

Editing Digital-7's HHead Descent value by fontforge gave me solution.